# AzureRM Automation PSWorkflow Runbook - error while attaching NIC to subnet

Tags: powershell, workflow

I'm trying to create a parallel Workflow script but facing some challenges while attaching NIC to existing Subnet. I'm getting the following error.

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : Cannot validate argument on
>   parameter 'SubnetId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
>   argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Following is my Workflow script which creates VNet, Subnet, NSG, PIP and tries to create NIC from AzureRM automation Runbook.

```
"Get Virtual Network Information" $gvnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork
-Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $SharedResourcesRGName

$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name "$VMName-NIC"
-ResourceGroupName $VMName -Location $VMLocation `
        -SubnetId $gvnet.Subnets[0].ID -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $gnsg.Id -Force
```

How do I get the value of Subnet in AzureRM Workflow runbook

Gulab Pasha

Comment: well, can you confirm that `$gvnet` is not empty?

Comment: unable paste complete output

Comment: why would you do this, edit the question and delete all the extra comments